# How do I color two halves of an html page

Tags: html, css

I am using material css to divide a page into two full-height columns, one of 7 grids and the other of 5 grids.

I want the background of first column to extend downwards. However what I see is that it fills color till the section there are elements.I know that it is correct but how do I make it stretch column wise.I tried flexbox but it does not help.

HTML section:

```css
 .row .s7{
background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s7 flex-container">
      first half
    </div>

    <div class="col s5">

    </div>
  </div>
```

The output is [image]
I want the greensection to extend completely till dow and fill half the page column wise

Comment: In your next question involving a snippet, you might want to learn about what that "tidy" button does.

Comment: I forgot to do that.sorry.

Comment: I don't know Materialize, but it makes little sense to have `.flex-container` on a flex-item. Even *sounds* wrong.

Comment: Otherwise how will I fix this.flex was my last resort.@connexo

Comment: not exactly I needs to be like page divided column vise into two On left green extending to the bottom and on right white @denmch

Comment: That's a little clearer. I tried to clarify that in an edit to the question: "I am using material css to divide a page into two full-height columns, one of 7 grids and the other of 5 grids."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you did not give it height
you can use this

```css
.row .s7{
background-color: grey;
height:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
          
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s7 flex-container">
      first half
    </div>

    <div class="col s5">

    </div>
  </div>
```

or remove height:800px; and place this

```
bottom:0;
top:0;
position:absolute;
```

or use this

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: Is there any other option without using position absolute as it is breaking my code(the snippet in the question was a small part of code)

Comment: Yes let me see. I will search.

Comment: I updated the answer use height:100vh dont use bottom:0;
top:0;
position:absolute;

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just pure division of the page, and you want responsiveness you can use flexbox.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-half"></div>
  <div class="second-half"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 1080px;
  width: 1920px;
}

.first-half {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.second-half {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: is it possible that I set the height and width of container to fit to screen instead of 1080 px and 1920 px?

Comment: @leo it can be whatever size you want.